# Eclipse CDT Plugin not working

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I have created a plugin to CDT that works fine when I test it under the runtime workbench.

However, when I export the plugin to a jar and drop it into the plugins directory of a clean CDT install, there is no trace of the plugin being loaded.

Any suggestions for things to check?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself. I had unused dependencies, and removing them fixed it...

Alan

Comment: Further to that, on another of my plugins I had been referencing dependencies with minimum version numbers which were not available in my target environment - in my case I was able to remove the minimum version numbers.